# Resolving local LAN hostnames on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dns

In a gist, this is my issue:

My router's hostname is 'thecenter'. (If I leave hostname empty, I can't resolve local hostnames at all)

Computer1 resolves all hostnames without problem, i.e. `http://livingroom/`

Computer2 will only resolve hostnames if you add the router's hostname after, i.e. `http://livingroom.thecenter/`

Both are running Windows 10. Both wired, connected to the same switch, which is connected to the central router.

What could be causing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem.

If I view network properties (Start Menu -> "View your network properties"), I find that the "problem" computer is missing the `DNS Domain Name` and `DNS Suffix` properties, where my working computer is not missing those properties.

I was able to fix this by switching to manual IP, then back to automatic DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Routers do not normally resolve hostnames in Windows 10 and you see this in your post.

For very small systems and networks like yours (and mine) use the Windows HOSTS file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) for keeping host names.

If you need to edit this file (HOSTS) and save the edits, you need to open Notepad with Run as Administrator, navigate the the HOSTS file, edit it and save, to keep the results.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts. In my case I fixed it by going into my routers LAN config and setting "RT-AX53U's Domain Name" from "" (nothing) to "home".

I found a post that said they could ping the host if they added a single dot . to the end of the hostname and that made me think that the hostname for local domain was missing. and so it