# Local DNS lookup doesn't work on Win 10 (hostname cannot be found from other devices)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I want to access my Win 10 computer (let's call it `ComputerName`) from my Android 10 and 12 devices via hostname (I call `ping ComputerName` on them),  but they can't find it and return:
`DNS error, Unknown host ComputerName`.

Here is all the info I think might help:

1. Computer has no IP and DNS specified and is set to DHCP.
2. On the router, DNS is set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
3. My setup is very simple, a router with a Win 10 build 19044 and two Android devices, v10 and 12, all get their IP via DHCP.
4. I do have like 5 VPN's installed but their (TAN) adapters are all disabled (their apps are not open).
5. I wanted to provide my `hosts` file but it's empty (all `#` comments).
6. Modem model is Tp-Link W8961N.
7. All devices are connected via Wi-Fi (2.4 Ghz).

even on the same computer when I run `nslookup ComputerName` in an elevated Command Prompt, it says:

```
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** dns.google can't find Laptop1: Non-existent domain
```

Why it's resorting to those external DNS's? Isn't it supposed to search in the LAN first? I thought of setting router's IP as first DNS server but I've never seen anyone do it in all my experience and every guide I've read and it should be obvious, IMHO.

But when I `ping ComputerName' it returns:

```
Pinging ComputerName[::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

(Why it's referring to it as `::1:`, isn't this IP6? I read everywhere to disable it always, haha.)

So far I've tried (, IIRC):

1. Changing the computer name and restart.
2. restarting DNS Service on the computer.
3. [Flushing DNS and other related commands](https://support.pearson.com/getsupport/s/article/Reset-an-Internet-Connection-Flush-DNS)
4. Resetting Network configs on the Android devices. As far as I searched, I can't reset DNS pool from modem.
5. Set static IP on the computer (and also reverting back to DHCP afterwards, both didn't work)
6. Probably more that I forgot, sorry.

I don't want to edit my hosts file to include the IP because the whole point of all this is to work with DHCP.

Here is result of `ipconfig /all` command:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ComputerName
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

   [Removed all VPN's infos, they are all Media disconnected]

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : [Removed]
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, November 17, 2022 7:08:29 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, November 20, 2022 7:08:28 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

My only guess as of now was an answer I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1530664/resolving-local-lan-hostnames-on-windows-10), which says:

> If I view network properties (Start Menu -> "View your network properties"), I find that the "problem" computer is missing the DNS Domain Name and DNS Suffix properties, where my working computer is not missing those properties.

And in that page `DNS domain name` and `DNS search suffix list` are empty. Maybe it is the case but I can't find how to fix it. I actually DID find how to add a colon to suffix to force something and it worked for people but I want my other devices find this computer, not vice versa.

Thank you for your time.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways a local hostname lookup can be done:

1. Using a local DNS server – typically your router, which collects device hostnames from DHCP lease requests. This is compatible with nslookup, but won't work for you, because you've manually configured a different DNS server (8.8.8.8) so that's where all unicast DNS queries go.

   (Disabling DHCP only adds another reason for it to not work, because the router doesn't know your hostname unless you send it as part of the DHCP request.)

   Run `nslookup ComputerName 192.168.1.1` to check whether the router has added your hostname to its internal DNS. Keep in mind that not all routers have this feature at all. (Sometimes it's disabled if an empty "domain search suffix" is set on the router.)
2. Using some kind of LAN-wide (multicast-based) name lookup protocol. Windows supports three – NBNS (obsolete, disabled with SMBv1); LLMNR; and mDNS.

   For the computer to be discoverable through LLMNR or mDNS, firewall rules need to allow the inbound UDP discovery packets (on ports 5355 and 5353 respectively) – normally the Windows Firewall allows them for "private" networks, but if you open `wf.msc` you can find the rules named "Network Discovery (LLMNR-UDP-In)" and "mDNS (UDP-In)". Enable both.

   (NetBIOS uses UDP ports 137 and 138. You only need it for ancient systems.)

Note that mDNS names always use `.local` as the suffix. Windows will automatically add it if you just query for "ComputerName", but other mDNS-using systems (Android, iOS, macOS, Linux) **require** the name to be specified as `ComputerName.local` for mDNS to work. (This also means .local shouldn't be used as the suffix for local DNS in your router, as the OS will disable mDNS if it detects a conflict.)

> Why it's resorting to those external DNS's? Isn't it supposed to search in the LAN first?

No – even if the rest of the OS does that, `nslookup` will not. It is strictly a unicast DNS client and will only speak to the DNS server that's configured in the OS.

(nslookup *could* query the router's internal DNS server, but your configuration tells it not to.)

Use PowerShell's `Resolve-DnsName` if you want to test mDNS/LLMNR in addition to DNS.

> I thought of setting router's IP as first DNS server but I've never seen anyone do it in all my experience and every guide I've read and it should be obvious, IMHO.

You've never seen anyone do it because that's *already the default* configuration in most home routers – the router's own address gets distributed as the only "DNS server" via DHCP, to have all devices use the router's built-in DNS cache (often with a feature to host a local DNS domain).

When people want to select their server manually, it's specifically because they no longer want to use their router's (which itself forwards to the ISP's) but would prefer a third-party service. If they want to return to using the router as their DNS server, they just switch back to "Obtain DNS server automatically".

> (Why it's referring to it as ::1:, isn't this IP6?

It is. Windows resolves its *own* hostname internally (without asking anything on the network), returning both the IPv4 and IPv6 loopback addresses (i.e. `127.0.0.1` and `::1`).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows; Go through active network adapter properties and disable IPv6.

In GNU/BSD/Linux based systems, it is easier as Avahi is configurable. I couldn't find similar way in Windows without disabling IPv6 completely.

---

**TLTR**

I was having similar issue with my setup

- 5 PCs (2 Win10 in remote location, 1 Win10 + 1 Mac + 1 Ubuntu locally)
- All firewall setup, re-verified
- The two location are in separate subnets 192.168.x.x
- All machines are part of secondary subnet using ZeroTier (3rd subnet in 192.168.x.x too)

I was using NoMachine to connect remote PCs. NoMachine detect hosts with `.local` domain but can't connect to them only using IP directly. Surprisingly same issue with all local machines.

So I tried debugging with `ping` command

```
C:\Users\user>ping 192.168.168.12

Pinging 192.168.168.12 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.168.12: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.12: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.12: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.168.12:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 52ms, Maximum = 62ms, Average = 58ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\user>ping cv4t

Pinging CV4T.local [fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=52ms
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=55ms
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=54ms
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=59ms

Ping statistics for fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 52ms, Maximum = 59ms, Average = 55ms

C:\Users\user>ping cv4t.local

Pinging CV4T.local [fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=52ms
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=61ms
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=52ms
Reply from fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7: time=52ms

Ping statistics for fe80::fa33:d123:2eb3:1628%7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 52ms, Maximum = 61ms, Average = 54ms
```

mDNS and hostname(netbios may be) resolves to IPv6.

After I disabled IPv6 in active adapter (ZeroTier VPN in my case). Both get resolved to IPv4.

[image: IPv6 in adapter properties - Windows 10]

```
C:\Users\user>ping cv4t.local

Pinging CV4T.local [192.168.168.17] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.168.17:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 50ms, Maximum = 62ms, Average = 53ms

C:\Users\user>ping cv4t

Pinging CV4T.local [192.168.168.17] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.168.17: bytes=32 time=78ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.168.17:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 52ms, Maximum = 78ms, Average = 62ms
```